# usage of IF statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

What is the difference between 2 statements, although  both does the same process, there has be some difference in between both of them

if(rising_edge clk) and
if rising_edge (clk)

Comment: simply : the first one is a compile error waiting to happen.

Comment: Only slightly less simply: it's less critically if syntax you're changing, but function syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The condition expression in an `if` statement is supposed to return a Boolean value.

A function call is of the form:

```vhdl
function_call ::=

    function_name [ ( actual_parameter_part ) ]

    actual_parameter_part ::=  parameter_association_list
```

Notice the required opening and closing parenthesis enclosing parameters (arguments).

```
 association_list ::= 
     association_element { , association_element }

 association_element ::= 
     [ formal_part => ] actual_part
```

The package declaration for package std_logic_1164 contains the declarations:

```
FUNCTION rising_edge  (SIGNAL s : std_ulogic) RETURN BOOLEAN;
FUNCTION falling_edge (SIGNAL s : std_ulogic) RETURN BOOLEAN;
```

Where we see these are both functions with single arguments that are signals.

Extended Baccus-Naur Form (EBNF, VHDL's definition, not the ISO standard) is normative when found in the body of the IEEE standard and on the syntax summary in an appendix.  Those opening and closing parentheses are required enclosing any parameters passed in function calls.

And more subtly then Brian or Fru1tbat allude, a function call syntax issue discoverable during analysis.

On the other hand if your question had been erroneous and you had meant the difference in the two functions the package body contains:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- edge detection
-------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION rising_edge  (SIGNAL s : std_ulogic) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
    RETURN (s'EVENT AND (To_X01(s) = '1') AND
                        (To_X01(s'LAST_VALUE) = '0'));
END;

FUNCTION falling_edge (SIGNAL s : std_ulogic) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
    RETURN (s'EVENT AND (To_X01(s) = '0') AND
                        (To_X01(s'LAST_VALUE) = '1'));
END;
```

Where we see that they are both sensitive to events (edges or *transitions*), and that rising_edge detects a positive transition while falling_edge a negative transition.

The To_X01 function calls effectively embrace 'H' to 'L' and 'L' to 'H' transitions which are valid std_ulogic values mappable to binary values.